# Differences between defining primary key - along with column name, at the end of create table stmt, adding primary key index after create table stmt

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

There are three ways I have seen to define primary keys.

1. Define along with its column name definition:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE test (
       id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       -- other fields
   );
   ```
2. Define the key at the end of the table definition:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE test (
      id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      -- other fields
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );
   ```
3. Adding primary key index after table creation. Generally I have seen this in phpMyAdmin's exported .sql files. (Does it depends on the storage engine used?)

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE test (
       id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
       -- other fields
   );

   ALTER TABLE test
       ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
       MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
   ```

What are the internal differences between all these methods?

Mostly I have seen that importing an SQL file having the 3rd method takes longer time than having other methods.

**Edit** (After **Bill Karwin** told that "(the) example(s) shows no import of data"):

The examples above don't contain `INSERT` queries, but what differences there will be if there are `INSERT` statements after each of these `CREATE TABLE` queries for inserting data in them?

Comment: There is no difference between any of them.

Comment: This (`id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`) is incorrect, because you cannot define `AUTO_INCRMENT` when there is no key.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for pointing out. I have made correction to the post accordingly.

Comment: I don't really think it's right to edit your question to a different one after the first one is answered. If you have a new question, ask a new question, and if this one is answered, mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the first two forms. It's only a syntax convenience if your primary key is a single column. But if you have a multi-column primary key, you must define the PK as a table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    other INT NOT NULL, 
   -- other fields
    PRIMARY KEY (id, other)
);
```

The third form is almost the same, because you define the primary key before inserting any data into the table. The only effect is that metadata is altered by the second DDL statement.

Some people claim that adding the primary key after importing data is faster, but this is not true for MySQL's default storage engine InnoDB. The table data is stored as a clustered index. If you don't declare your own primary key, another row id is created implicitly, and this becomes the key for the clustered index. So you're inserting into an index one way or the other.

It's possible that in the old MyISAM storage engine, inserting data to a table with no primary key is a little faster. But you have to count the extra time it takes to add the primary key after you're done inserting data.

In any case, your example shows no import of data, so it's moot.

Comment: But if the dump file contains values for the `id` column, the third method has to check for duplicates when it's inserting. The implicit cluster index doesn't require validation, does it?

Comment: Feel free to test it! I think if you add the time to build the PK after data import, it'll be a wash.

Comment: Also: don't use MyISAM.

Comment: It's very possible that my intuition is shaped from years of using MyISAM at work. When we create temp tables in scripts, we always add the indexes after populating them.

Comment: At my current job, we monitor every database for tables that are not InnoDB, and we warn the developers when we find one (except for the system schemas).

Comment: We use InnoDB for all new tables, but much of our architecture is 10-15 years old.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have made changes at the end of the post regarding your statement "example shows no import of data".

Comment: There will still be no difference in the logical function of the table. The most that would happen is that the internal storage might be slightly different, but the performance and query results would be the same.